# Type error: No overload matches this call - TypeScript, NextJS, styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I'm trying to render icons in my footer but keep getting a "Type error: No overload matches this call" error next to my StyledIconsWrapper. It's only an issue because that stops Vercel from deploying, otherwise the code works fine.

Here's my code:

```
interface StyledIconsProps {
  name: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  color: string;
  viewBox: string;
  externalUrl: string;
}

const socials = [
  {
    name: "instagram",
    width: 22,
    height: 22,
    color: "currentColor",
    viewBox: "0 0 32 32",
    externalUrl: "https://www.instagram.com/",
  },
];

export const FooterIcons = (): ReactElement => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <IconWrapper>
      <IconContainer>
        <Icon name="logoTl_White_L" width={150} height={33} color="currentColor" />
        We build digital shapers.
      </IconContainer>
      <StyledIconsWrapper color={colors.neutrals.white}>
        {socials.map(({ name, width, height, color, viewBox, externalUrl }) => {
          return (
            <StyledIcon
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              href={externalUrl}
              key={name}
              color={color}
            >
              <Icon name={name} width={width} height={height} color={color} viewBox={viewBox} />
            </StyledIcon>
          );
        })}
      </StyledIconsWrapper>
    </IconWrapper>
  );
};
```

And my StyledIconsWrapper:

```
const StyledIconsWrapper = styled.div<StyledIconsProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 10px;

  & > * {
    color: ${({ color }) => color};
  }
`;
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: Please show a full error message. There is usually exhaustive message about what went wrong

Comment: "No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { children?: ReactNode; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 259 more ...; externalUrl: string; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ children?: ReactNode; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; " and more

Comment: Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", DefaultTheme, StyledIconsProps, never, "div", "div">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", ... 4 more ..., "div">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined; ... 259 more ...; externalUrl: string; }': name, width, ...

Comment: `styled.div<Pick<StyledIconsProps, 'color'>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your Props are all required, so the element expects them all to be defined, not only `color`. You could change your props to be:

```js
interface StyledIconsProps {
  name?: string
  width?: number
  height?: number
  color: string
  viewBox?: string
  externalUrl?: string
}
```

Or change your styled div to only take color:

```js
const StyledIconsWrapper = styled.div<{color: string}>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 10px;

  & > * {
    color: ${({ color }) => color};
  }
`
```

Comment: I understand what the issue was now - thanks so much for the solution and the explanation!